# Multiple BarChart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to build a multiple Bar Chart in Power BI for my data

and I want to display 3 dept counts in 1 graph

something like this

[image]

My data looks like this

[image]

```
ID  HRDeptEmpCount  ITDeptEmpCount  FinDeptEmpCount Option1 Option2 Option3
1   4               5               8               Yes     Blue    1000
2   20+             6               20+             No      Red     1000
3   16              20+             3               Yes     Green   1000
4   4               15              5               Yes     Red     2000
5   7               11              16              Yes     Red     1000
6   20+             20+             20+             Yes     White   1000
7   13              16              3               No      Blue    1000
8   6               4               6               No      Green   3000
9   4               9               14              Yes     Blue    1000
10  20+             10              2               No      White   2000
11  1               20+             5               No      Red     1000
12  15              4               20+             No      Red     3000
13  9               2               12              Yes     Green   1000
```

I tried this way but i can not show all 3 deprtment counts in 1 graph

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps try to change the fields of your graph. Can you try to swap your axis and the Value?

Comment: gives meaning less results